# ElasticSearch/Nest: Query func – can't cast from interface to implementation at runtime

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

When implementing a default base func for my queries typed with an interface

```
private static Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<ISearchable>, QueryContainer> _filterBase = f => f
        .Term(t => t.Status, 2);
```

and later on cast it to a version typed with an implemenation of the interface

```
var filterBase = (Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<Event>, QueryContainer>) _filterBase;
```

I get a cast exception at runtime:

```
Unable to cast object of type
'System.Func`2[Nest.QueryContainerDescriptor`1[Kompi.ElasticSearch.Test.ISearchable],Nest.QueryContainer]' to type
'System.Func`2[Nest.QueryContainerDescriptor`1[Kompi.ElasticSearch.Test.Event],Nest.QueryContainer]'
```

My class implementations are basically:

```
public interface ISearchable
{
    int Status { get; set; }
}
public class MainEntityBase : ISearchable
{
    public int Status { set; get; }
    public bool Active { set; get; }
}
public class Event : MainEntityBase, ILocatable
{
    [Keyword]
    public int Id { set; get; }

    [Text]
    public string Name { set; get; }

    [Text]
    public string Description { set; get; }
}
```

If I skip MainEntityBase, there's not difference.

Any hints appreciated, thx in advance.

Comment: Not all `ISearchable` may be `Event` is the issue

Comment: Jesus, my brain. Thanks a load. Are you comfortable with Nest and have a clou about achieving the goal to prepare default queries?